# Python: How to use one dictionary to use to decode the other?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Say if I had two dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
d2 = {'a':'b', 'b':'b', 'a':'a'}
```

How can I use dictionary d1 as the rules to decode d2, such as:

```
def decode(dict_rules, dict_script):
    //do something
    return dict_result

decode(d1,d2)
>> {1:2, 2:2, 1:1}
```

Comment: You can't. `d2` is not a valid dictionary - it has a duplicate key `'a'` which is simply impossible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course it can be written much shorter, but here a version to see the principle:

```
result_list = list()
result_dict = dict()
for d2_key in d2.keys():
    d2_key_decoded = d1[d2_key]
    d2_value = d2[d2_key]
    d2_value_decoded = d1[d2_value]
    result_dict[d2_key_decoded] = d2_value_decoded
    # add a tuple to the result list  
    result_list.append((d2_key_decoded, d2_value_decoded))
```

the result might be unexpected - because the resulting dict would have entries with the same key, what is not possible, so the key 1 is overwritten:

```
>>> # equals to : 
>>> result_dict[1] = 2
>>> result_dict[2] = 2
>>> result_dict[1] = 1
>>> # Result : {1:1, 2:2}

>>> # therefore I added a list of Tuples as result : 
>>> # [(1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
```

but as @Patrik Artner pointed out, that is not possible, because already the input dictionary can not have duplicate keys !

Comment: Sorry I forgot that dictionaries cannot have entries with the same key- could it be returned as a nested list instead? So that the message is decoded?